# Web Map Service

Tags: wms

How can I convert this XML from EPSG::-27700 to EPSG::4326?

http://metaspatial.net/cgi-bin/ogc-wms.xml?VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&LAYERS=DTM,Overview,Raster_250K,Topography,nationalparks,Infrastructure,Places&STYLES=,,,,,,&CRS=EPSG:27700&BBOX=424735.97883597884,96026.98412698413,467064.02116402116,127773.01587301587&WIDTH=400&HEIGHT=300&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xffffff&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&

Comment: I do not see any XML anywhere. Maybe you want to change the CRS value and corresponding BBOX?

Comment: You will only get OS (raster) tiles in OSGB36 projection [27700] - but you can reproject the vector data. https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

Answer (score 2):

First check that the WMS you are consuming supports the projection you want to use by issuing a GetCapabilities request, in this case like:

http://metaspatial.net/cgi-bin/ogc-wms.xml?VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&

We can see that the service supports the following CRS:

`<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:27700</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4258</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:29903</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:2157</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3035</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4937</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3034</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4936</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3038</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3039</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3040</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3041</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3042</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3043</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3044</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3045</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3046</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3047</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3048</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3049</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3050</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3051</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:900913</CRS>`

Then issue a GetMap request specifying  the CRS you want `CRS=EPSG:4326&` and the bounding box you need in those coordinates, for example like:

http://metaspatial.net/cgi-bin/ogc-wms.xml?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=52.97701162003504294,-3.226702304964539358,55.26821673989402939,-0.9489590248226960068&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=846&HEIGHT=851&LAYERS=OGC-WMS_reference-server_with_OrdnanceSurvey-OpenSpace-data&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&

Gives:
[image: GetMap result]